# 3D вращение элемента мышкой html

Tags: javascript, html, анимация, 3dsmax

Нужно реализовать подобный функционал

http://www-shon-su.filesusr.com/html/bd5af2_86ec48938c9500c2ac5d6ec467d61d41.html

В примере выше используется множества картинок. Как лучше сделать, так же или есть иной способ?

Comment: Опишите в самом вопросе, что вам нужно.

Comment: Можно через 3D модель, но чтобы добиться такой чёткости вы повесите все браузеры. В принципе threesixty-slider нормальное решение. https://github.com/creativeaura/threesixty-slider

Comment: @АндрейProjectSoft Вы скинули такой же пример, который и я) Но грузится это быстрее, чем мой. Спасибо, попробую

Comment: @Tard это не пример. Это оригинал. Вы в репозитории разработчика и соответственно получаете полное описание и документацию по данному плагину.